# Escribir sentencias preparadas de forma segura

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría saber si es seguro escribir sentencias preparadas utilizando la función bind_param() de esta forma?

```
$sentence_1 = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?");
$sentence_1->bind_param("i", $id);
$sentence_1->execute();
```

O tiene riesgo de inyecciones SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) de PHP es seguro por:

- Estas pasando un marcador de posición determinado por el carácter ?
- Al haber pasado dicho marcador la consulta está preparada y a la espera de dicho valor
- El uso de bind_param lo que implica es agregar un parámetro a tu SELECT como variable
- Además al pasar el parámetro i estás indicando que el valor esperado es un entero
- Siempre que tu consulta reciba valores dinámicos, es decir valores enviados por el usuario inficalod con marcadores de posición